# I am not able to use product name like 5" ABCD in Magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, product-page, breadcrumbs

When i use double quotes in product name Magento2 product page is breaking.

Not Rendering Images , Tabs etc

getting below js error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 120
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getData (main.js:58)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDocument.apply (main.js:74)
    at fire (jquery.js:3232)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3542)
    at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2967)
    at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-migrate.js:225)
    at jQuery (jquery.js:75)
```

I debug and found its breaking from breadcrumb due to double quote in name.

```
{
   "breadcrumbs": {
       "categoryUrlSuffix": ".html",
       "useCategoryPathInUrl": 0,
       "product": "5" ABCD"
   }
}
```

SO **How can i use double quotes in name** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Read Following link for your solution.

[issues-14977](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14977)

[changes file 16594](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/16594/files)

[changes file 15521](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/15521/files)